# python 関数をリストへ

Tags: python, python3

```
['12:00～15:00', '18:00～23:30', '12:00～15:00', '18:00～24:00']
```

というリストがあったときに、最初の二項を取り出してそれを編集して
`12:00～23:30` と `15:00～18:00` を出力したいです（営業時間と休み時間）

ただ`list2 = [list1(0),list1(1)]`として関数をリストに入れるとエラーが出てしまいます。
解決策はありますか。

```
list1 = ['12:00～15:00', '18:00～23:30', '12:00～15:00', '18:00～24:00']

list2 = [list1(0),list1(1)]
list2.split("～")
print(list2(0)+"～"+list2(3))
print(list2(1)+"～"+list2(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

記号が違います。リストのインデックスは `[ ]` です。

```
list2 = [list1[0], list1[1]]
```

また、最初の 2 つということであればリストのスライスも使えます。

```
list2 = list1[:2]
```

Comment: @IHL  > `その後のsplit` とありますが、ご認識の通りこの`split`は文字列型に対するメソッドであるため、リストに対して使うことはできません。また、 `join` をしてしまうと意図通りにはうごかない結果になります。このため、 `map(lambda x:x.split("〜"), list2)` として、 `list2` の各要素に対して実行するのがよいでしょう。